# Magento 2 : Where is block code located

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.2, blocks, frontend

In the luma theme, in the home block, it starts with the code 
`div class="blocks-promo"`.

I would like to learn more these block classes so that I know how to use them going forward. i.e. I need some documentation, or at least the code so that I can figure out how to use, extend, modify, etc.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: This is a class name `div class="blocks-promo"` and not a block, block in magento mean other thing eg: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/Price.php` is a Magento block

Answer (score 1):

This is a class name `div class="blocks-promo"` and not a block, block in Magento mean other thing eg: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/Price.php` is a Magento block.

I guess you have found this class in some template and you want to get the related block of that template right ? if it is, a simple way to do is to `enable the template path hints` AND `Block name hints` then you will find what you need.

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled
>   Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes
>
> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Add Block Names
>   to Hints > Yes

**Note:** Don't forget to change storeview scope on the top left corner.

[image]

**Right:** the block type.

**Left:** the phtml path.